# How to fake the screen resolution for urllib.request.urlopen requests?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, urllib, screen-resolution

I noticed, that when I access web pages via the urllib library, I get different source code compared to accessing the same page with a standard web browser.
Especially some image links point to lower resolution versions of the image.

If this is related to the detected screen resolution when loading a web page, is there a way to fake it when loading with `urllib.request.urlopen`? If one provides a `Request` object, one can spoof some header information, is there something similar for the screen resolution? Is it possible to fill the javascript variable `screen` with some information by hand?

I know there exist some third party libraries like "Selenium WebDriver" and the like, but I want to use only the standard library.